# List attributes of a sublass instance in Python

Tags: python, introspection, legacy

I'm trying to build some "ORM like" behavior in Python. To do this I have a Model class and would like to produce any kind of subclasses. My problem is when I try to list the attributes of my subclasses instances. 
Here is my Model class:

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.className = type(self).__name__

    def listAttributes(self):
        from modules.users.user import User
        instance = User()
        meta = vars(instance)
```

And a User subclass :

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.FieldChar()
    password = models.FieldChar()
    age = models.FieldInteger()
```

When I invoke the listAttributes method from a User instance, I don't have what I expect, but probably what I should: **the meta var contains only className**. Here's how I invoke the method:

```
from modules.users import user
user = user.User()
user.listAttributes()
```

Same behavior when I override the listAttributes method in User():

```
def listAttributes(self):
    meta = vars(self)
    print(meta)
```

Is there a way to list the attribute of the object from which I call the listAttributes method?

Thanks for your lights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your listAttributes method a classmethod and try the following:

```
class Model(object):
    @classmethod
    def listAttributes(cls):
        return [
            a for a in dir(cls) if not
            callable(getattr(cls, a)) and not 
            a.startswith("__")
        ]
```

If you just want to have the attributes that are of your "Fields" type (FieldChar, FieldInt...) then you could make a base class for the fields called e.g. ModelField and also check your attributes against this base type:

```
class Model(object):
    @classmethod
    def listAttributes(cls):
        attributes = []
        for a in dir(cls):
            if ((not callable(getattr(cls, a)) and not
                 a.startswith("__") and
                 getattr(cls, a).__class__.__bases__[0] == ModelField)):
                attributes.append(a)
```

You could even return the objects instead of just the names. Or append the objects to a dict in your Model class (to make usage in your code easier). I constructed my ORM like this:

```
class ModelField(object):
    ...

class IntField(ModelField):
    ...

class Model(object):
    id = IntField(pk=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.modelFields
        except AttributeError:
            self.__class__.introspect()
        for key, modelfield in self.modelFields.items():
            setattr(self, key, kwargs.get(key, None))

    @classmethod
    def introspect(cls):
        cls.modelFields = {}
        for a in dir(cls):
            if ((not callable(getattr(cls, a)) and not
                 a.startswith("__") and
                 getattr(cls, a).__class__.__bases__[0] == ModelField)):
                cls.modelFields[a] = getattr(cls, a)
```

Then i used cls.introspect to set up the modelFields dict and use this dict to e.g. autogenerate a db-table or construct querys by using attributes of the ModelField class.

Comment: It's totally what I was looking for. I lost hope of that level of introspection level in Python. Thanx for that exhaustive answer